# Set Expires HTTP header for files in RootFolder

Tags: list, custom-list, host-header

Our custom list definition stores some static files in the root folder (and sub-folders). Is there a way to manipulate the HTTP response header for these files to treat them as static (e.g., by setting the Expires header)?

We are considering using [Disk-based Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa604896.aspx), but are concerned about authorization (not all users are allowed to see the static content).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "static"? If you mean that nobody should be able to delete them? This could be done with an event receiver on the ItemDeleting event

Comment: I am referring to images which will never change. We cannot store them in _layouts/ because they are specific to a list and other data (version).

Answer (score 1):

Normally these kind images are stored in `_LAYOUTS` (as you mention) or in `Style Library` in the site collection root, but they could be stored in any library really.

Take a look at the permission for `Style Library` and you will see your standard Visitors group has Read permissions only to this library. Note also that Members have Contribute permissions, so if you dont want them to have this permission on your images, create a sub folder and set even stricter permissions here, or create a new library for your images with special permissions.

You can read more about permissions in SharePoint [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx).